# Notepad++ workspace used at startup

Tags: notepad++

I have started using Notepad++ Workspace tree structures and am finding this functionality great.
Menu options are View > Project > Project Panel 1    (also Project Panel 2 and Project Panel 3 are here also)

Notepad++ for me, seems to always open up with Project Panel 3 showing.

I wondered if it was possible to have Workspace / Project Panel 1 showing upon open of Notepad++ instead of Project Panel 3 ?

I have realized today that there is 3 tabs at the bottom of this "Project Panel" to switch between the three rather than using menu options, so this makes this question lower priority/concern.
I couldn't see any options in the Settings > Preferences section.